# Blender object being imported in Unity is invisible

Tags: modeling, objects, import, unity, .fbx

I'm trying to make a very simple object in Blender and export it to Unity. The object is a simple square that has a glowing (neon-style-like) rim (or frame).
What I did was adding square, inserting faces to create an inner square. Then I separated the planes (inner square and outer frame) to assing different materials to them. Then I assinged a material with red color and red emission to the frame (all I can think of to make it look neon-style) and just some black color material to the inner squre.
I selected both objects and exported as .fbx, then imported in Unity. But when I add this object to scene, it is invisible. What did I do wrong?

[I'm very new to Unity and really used Blender for the first time]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your plane is in $XY$ in blender, it's actually in $XZ$ in unity if you exported by default values, so you can't see it by its side.
Try change to 3d view and see if this is the issue

Also, it could be mesh normals which determines front faces. Blender renders both faces, front and back but in unity its just front by default, but in this case I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: Oh, you were so right! I updated the question so you can see how it looked like. The color of the material made in blender doesn't look the same in Unity. But since I have now two different planes contained in the object, I can create individual materials for them in Unity itself